# Knitr package option strip.white is ignored

Tags: r, latex, knitr, whitespace

My colleague and I work together in R on a manual. We do this in an RMD-file. We knit the RMD file to a PDF.

The styling is important and we want to preserve leading whitespaces. So we set this package option:

`knitr::opts_chunk$set(tidy.opts = list(width.cutoff = 60), tidy = TRUE, strip.white = FALSE, echo = TRUE)`

When I knit the document, whitespaces are preserved. But when my colleague does so, they get stripped. It seems like the `strip.white = FALSE` option is ignored.

We both have R version 3.5.1 and MikTex 2.9. Our Global Options for Sweave are exactly the same. We both use the same latex template (default-1.17.0.2.tex).

What could cause the difference in whitespacing between my colleague's PDF and mine?

Comment: Perhaps you didn't have the **formatR** package installed, and your colleague did? You two can put `sessionInfo()` in your Rmd and compare the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, Yihui, for looking into our issue and for your quick response. Yes, using `sessionInfo()` I found out that **formatR** was managing the layout of my **R** code. After deinstalling this package I was able to manage the appearance of the code using **knitr** options again.

Problem solved.